# Exception RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View

Tags: java, android

Помогите разобраться почему вылетает ошибка!!!! Когда процесс авторизации прошел, то вьюшка открывается и когда есть интернет и авторизация прошла,то VIEW открывается, а вот когда не прошел авторизацию, то нет и когда интернета на устройстве нету, тогда тоже не открывается!

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_item_board0);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.news_name1235);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar!=null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        }

        ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true) {

                if (!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Вам надо пройти процесс авторизации...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    mainLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);
                    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_login2, mainLayout1, false);
                    mainLayout1.addView(view);

                    } else {

                        код............................

                                }
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                               }});}} else {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Нет соединения с Интернетом. Пожалуйста подключитесь к Интернету...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lenta, mainLayout, false);
            mainLayout.addView(view);
                }}
}
```

ошибка такая:

> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1315)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                             at
>   calculation.material.oma.sviter.by.board.BoardActivity.onCreate(BoardActivity.java:85)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)

бьет вот сюда:
**`mainLayout1.addView(view);`**

Comment: Покажите xml разметку (файл recycler_item_board0.xml). У вас там точно есть элемент с id `main_layout_id`?

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id)` ничего не находит, вот и ошибка в результате.

Comment: поняла...спасибо